# .NET Core 2.1 Override Automatic Model Validation

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core-2.1

In the latest .NET Core 2.1, an automatic validation for the model state validation is introduced (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/02/asp-net-core-2-1-roadmap/#mvc).

Previously I could override the validation error response by the following code below:

```
public class ApiValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new context.ModelState);
        }

    base.OnActionExecuting(context);
}
```

But now it no longer works. The validation errors is responded without entering the override method.

Anyone has any clue?
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you only need to remove the ApiController attribute. That would 'revert' the logic to the 'old' style.

Comment: @Silvermind you are absolutely right. Silly of me for not thinking of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you'd like to keep using the `ApiController` attribute (which has other functions like disabling conventional routing and allowing model binding without adding `[FromBody]` parameter attributes), you might be able to do it via this in your `Startup.cs` file:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

That will make it so that if the ModelState is invalid it won't automatically return a 400 error.

Comment: You save my life, I have been looking this code for a long time

Comment: I also needed options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidateModelAttribute)); in mvc options for this to work, see Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 11):

I was recently asked by a friend about this and my approach was to replace the default `ModalStateInvalidFilter` by a custom one.

In my test I've implemented the suggestion from [here](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/validation-response-aspnet-core-webapi/) and then:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidateModelAttribute));
});


services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options => { options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true; });
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this as well as the blog post :)