# ASP.NET CORE: Custom validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

### Background

I have a web api that written with asp.net core v2.1. This is the function which exposed by my service:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("submit")]
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> DoIt(CustomModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return new StatusCodeResult(403); // Custom 403 will be here.

    // ...
}
```

And this is the `CustomModel`:

```
public class CustomModel
{
    [Required]
    public int MagicNumber { get; set; }
}
```

This combination (method+model) is working fine until the client don't provide the `MagicNumber` to the server.

### The Problem

In contrast to the old asp.net (.net framework), when model validation is failed - an automatic 403 error message is sent to the client.

I want to prevent this default behavior and give a custom error message to the user. I prefer to define a custom response like this way:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("submit")]
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Submit(CustomModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return new CustomErrorCode_BadRequest();
    //...
}
```

### Things I tried

The only way that I could prevent the automatic "bad-request" response is by adding this code to the `Startup.cs` file

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.ModelValidatorProviders.Clear());
```

After adding this line of code, I was able to reach my `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` statement. Before that, the request was blocked on earlier step. Unfortenetly, the `ModelState.IsValid` return always `true` (no matter what is the input). I guess that this is because I "cleared" all of the validators - which sounds like a bad idea.

How it should be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51522487/3085985

Comment: Do you have the [ApiController] attribute on your class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize automatic response on validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439664/customize-automatic-response-on-validation-error)

Comment: It sounds like rather than *disabling* the automatic response, you'd like to *customise* it. I've linked another question that explains how to do something like this. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51870603/intercept-bad-requests-before-reaching-controller-in-asp-net-core/51872393) might also help.

Comment: @Sakuto - yes. I already added the [ApiController] attribute.

Comment: @Compufreak - Yes! this solved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Core 2.1 Override Automatic Model Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125569/net-core-2-1-override-automatic-model-validation)

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever Well, just for your information if you didn't know yet. This behavior is added by this attribute in particular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @Compufreak (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51522487/3085985) Adding this code to `Starup.cs` solved the problem:

```
    services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(opt =>
    {
        opt.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    });
```